# how to achieve Read/Write on YL160 Magnetic Stripe 4in 1 encoder?

Tags: c++, magnetic-cards

i have recently bought a Magnetic Reader/Writer from China (**YL160 4 in 1 Reader/Writer**)
and it came with the Demo application along with the API.
What i need mainly from this device is Magnetic Stripe Write, i need to write data to a blank HiCo magnetic card.

When i open the demo application under the magnetic stripe tab they are two columns

1. Read-Only
2. Read Write

[image: The Demo Application]

the Read-Only works but the Read/Write doesn't, it refers me to Read-only which suggests the devices doesn't have write capabilities so i went into an API to check in case the demo app is buggy and here is what i found inside *160.h* Header file

```
extern int _stdcall MSR_Init(void);
extern void _stdcall MSR_Exit(void);
extern int _stdcall MSR_DoCancel(void);
extern int _stdcall MSR_Read(void);
extern int _stdcall MSR_Write(unsigned char *TK1Dat, unsigned char *TK2Dat, unsigned char *TK3Dat);
extern int _stdcall MSR_Read_ASCII(void);
extern int _stdcall MSR_Write_ASCII(char *trace1, char *trace2, char *trace3);
extern int _stdcall MSR_Erase(unsigned char mode);
extern int _stdcall MSR_GetTrackData(unsigned char *TK1Dat, unsigned char *TK2Dat, unsigned char *TK3Dat);

extern int _stdcall MSR_Set_HiCo ();
extern int _stdcall MSR_Set_LoCo ();
extern int _stdcall MSR_Get_CoStatus(unsigned char *status);
extern int _stdcall Msr_ChangeAscii(unsigned char *TK1Dat, unsigned char *TK2Dat, unsigned char *TK3Dat);
extern int _stdcall MSR_Write_status(void);
extern int _stdcall MSR_Fast_Init(int portnum);
extern int _stdcall MSR_Get_HwInfo (char *info);
extern void _stdcall MSR_BeepOff (void);
extern void _stdcall MSR_BeepOn (void);
extern int _stdcall MSR_Erase_status(void);
extern int _stdcall MSR_ASC_Read(void);
extern int __stdcall auto_init(void)
```

And Then This

```
extern void __stdcall   MagOpen(void);
extern void __stdcall   MagClose(void);
extern void  __stdcall   MagReset(void);
extern unsigned char __stdcall   MagSwiped(void);
extern unsigned char  __stdcall  MagRead(unsigned char *Track1, unsigned char *Track2,unsigned char *Track3);
```

Then i thought maybe the demo application is using the **MagOpen()** to switch the device to Read Mode but there is no function to switch the device to *Write Mode*.
i haven't tested **MagOpen()** with **MSR_Write()**.
Inside the API folder there is Lib160.dll and Lib160.lib

i have tried to disassemble the *Lib160.dll* with *IDA Pro* to see whats happening in **MagOpen** so i can maybe implement the Write Mode Switch but IDA Pro shows an error about Input.
Further more this device appears in the Device Manager as *Microsoft Usbccid Smart Card Reader (WUDF)* under Smart Card Readers not on COM Port or HID.

*Now Here are My questions*

**Is it possible to Check if the Magnetic Head is capable of Write? if yes How?**

**Can i Replace the Magnetic head with the one with Write Capabilities?**

Please help i need help, Coding is not a problem but the problem is where to start

Thank you

Comment: Looks like it can't write magnetic data according to the bang good product description

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's more of a hardware question than a programming one

Comment: @AlanBirtles yeah you are right its hardware issue

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If someone else like me also ended up here after searching for the software that should ship with the YL160, the SDK can be downloaded here: https://www.szzcs.com/Down_complex.aspx?FId=n4:4:4

Comment: OP: Did you try looking at the Lib160.dll that's included in the SDK (linked above) inside of a dissassembler? I noticed it's much larger than the Lib160.dll that comes with the demo app in the CD, but when I tried to run it through DotPeek I didn't see any symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the product image on Amazon (See ASIN # B09L17C3PG):

[image]

Magnetic cards are read-only.